# C# CheckDisk how do I get part of the output

Tags: c#, string, split, trim

I am trying to make a GUI for checkdisk it works but it returns a big string like this :

The type of the file system is NTFS.

```
WARNING!  F parameter not specified.
Running CHKDSK in read-only mode.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
Progress: 0 of 203264 done; Stage:  0%; Total:  0%; ETA:   0:09:48    
Progress: 10497 of 203264 done; Stage:  5%; Total:  1%; ETA:   0:09:39 .  
Progress: 23041 of 203264 done; Stage: 11%; Total:  3%; ETA:   0:09:26 .. 
Progress: 35329 of 203264 done; Stage: 17%; Total:  5%; ETA:   0:00:22 ...
Progress: 47105 of 203264 done; Stage: 23%; Total:  7%; ETA:   0:00:22    
Progress: 58369 of 203264 done; Stage: 28%; Total:  9%; ETA:   0:00:22 .  
Progress: 69889 of 203264 done; Stage: 34%; Total: 11%; ETA:   0:00:22 .. 
Progress: 82433 of 203264 done; Stage: 40%; Total: 13%; ETA:   0:00:22 ...
Progress: 94977 of 203264 done; Stage: 46%; Total: 15%; ETA:   0:00:20    
Progress: 107265 of 203264 done; Stage: 52%; Total: 17%; ETA:   0:00:20 .  
Progress: 119553 of 203264 done; Stage: 58%; Total: 19%; ETA:   0:00:20 .. 
Progress: 131329 of 203264 done; Stage: 64%; Total: 21%; ETA:   0:00:20 ...
Progress: 143873 of 203264 done; Stage: 70%; Total: 23%; ETA:   0:00:19    
Progress: 156161 of 203264 done; Stage: 76%; Total: 25%; ETA:   0:00:19 .  
Progress: 168118 of 203264 done; Stage: 82%; Total: 27%; ETA:   0:00:19 .. 
Progress: 180481 of 203264 done; Stage: 88%; Total: 29%; ETA:   0:00:17 ...
Progress: 192769 of 203264 done; Stage: 94%; Total: 32%; ETA:   0:00:17    
Progress: 203264 of 203264 done; Stage: 100%; Total: 33%; ETA:   0:00:17 .  


  203264 file records processed.                                                        

File verification completed.
Progress: 0 of 0 done; Stage: 99%; Total: 34%; ETA:   0:00:17 .. 


  0 large file records processed.                                   

Progress: 0 of 0 done; Stage: 99%; Total: 34%; ETA:   0:00:17 ...


  0 bad file records processed.                                     


Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
Progress: 10520 of 225234 done; Stage:  4%; Total: 36%; ETA:   0:00:15    
Progress: 89156 of 225234 done; Stage: 39%; Total: 49%; ETA:   0:00:09 .  
Progress: 172336 of 225234 done; Stage: 76%; Total: 63%; ETA:   0:00:06 .. 
Progress: 203306 of 225234 done; Stage: 90%; Total: 68%; ETA:   0:00:04 ...
Progress: 203561 of 225234 done; Stage: 90%; Total: 68%; ETA:   0:00:04    
Progress: 203676 of 225234 done; Stage: 90%; Total: 69%; ETA:   0:00:04 .  
Progress: 203718 of 225234 done; Stage: 90%; Total: 69%; ETA:   0:00:04 .. 
Progress: 203741 of 225234 done; Stage: 90%; Total: 69%; ETA:   0:00:04 ...
Progress: 203761 of 225234 done; Stage: 90%; Total: 69%; ETA:   0:00:04    
Progress: 203775 of 225234 done; Stage: 90%; Total: 69%; ETA:   0:00:04 .  
Progress: 203792 of 225234 done; Stage: 90%; Total: 69%; ETA:   0:00:04 .. 
Progress: 203813 of 225234 done; Stage: 90%; Total: 69%; ETA:   0:00:04 ...
Progress: 203826 of 225234 done; Stage: 90%; Total: 69%; ETA:   0:00:04    
Progress: 203835 of 225234 done; Stage: 90%; Total: 69%; ETA:   0:00:05 .  
Progress: 203840 of 225234 done; Stage: 90%; Total: 69%; ETA:   0:00:05 .. 
Progress: 203846 of 225234 done; Stage: 90%; Total: 69%; ETA:   0:00:06 ...
Progress: 203855 of 225234 done; Stage: 90%; Total: 69%; ETA:   0:00:06    
Progress: 203862 of 225234 done; Stage: 90%; Total: 70%; ETA:   0:00:06 .  
Progress: 204035 of 225234 done; Stage: 90%; Total: 70%; ETA:   0:00:06 .. 
Progress: 204123 of 225234 done; Stage: 90%; Total: 70%; ETA:   0:00:06 ...
Progress: 204142 of 225234 done; Stage: 90%; Total: 70%; ETA:   0:00:06    
Progress: 204165 of 225234 done; Stage: 90%; Total: 70%; ETA:   0:00:06 .  
Progress: 204182 of 225234 done; Stage: 90%; Total: 71%; ETA:   0:00:06 .. 
Progress: 204234 of 225234 done; Stage: 90%; Total: 71%; ETA:   0:00:06 ...
Progress: 204240 of 225234 done; Stage: 90%; Total: 72%; ETA:   0:00:06    
Progress: 204249 of 225234 done; Stage: 90%; Total: 72%; ETA:   0:00:06 .  
Progress: 204264 of 225234 done; Stage: 90%; Total: 72%; ETA:   0:00:06 .. 
Progress: 204418 of 225234 done; Stage: 90%; Total: 72%; ETA:   0:00:08 ...
Progress: 204554 of 225234 done; Stage: 90%; Total: 73%; ETA:   0:00:08    
Progress: 204710 of 225234 done; Stage: 90%; Total: 73%; ETA:   0:00:08 .  
Progress: 204771 of 225234 done; Stage: 90%; Total: 73%; ETA:   0:00:08 .. 
Progress: 204839 of 225234 done; Stage: 90%; Total: 73%; ETA:   0:00:08 ...
Progress: 204966 of 225234 done; Stage: 91%; Total: 73%; ETA:   0:00:08    
Progress: 205132 of 225234 done; Stage: 91%; Total: 73%; ETA:   0:00:08 .  
Progress: 205148 of 225234 done; Stage: 91%; Total: 74%; ETA:   0:00:08 .. 
Progress: 205167 of 225234 done; Stage: 91%; Total: 74%; ETA:   0:00:08 ...
Progress: 205179 of 225234 done; Stage: 91%; Total: 74%; ETA:   0:00:08    
Progress: 205213 of 225234 done; Stage: 91%; Total: 75%; ETA:   0:00:08 .  
Progress: 205268 of 225234 done; Stage: 91%; Total: 75%; ETA:   0:00:08 .. 
Progress: 205373 of 225234 done; Stage: 91%; Total: 75%; ETA:   0:00:08 ...
Progress: 205517 of 225234 done; Stage: 91%; Total: 75%; ETA:   0:00:08    
Progress: 205657 of 225234 done; Stage: 91%; Total: 75%; ETA:   0:00:08 .  
Progress: 205787 of 225234 done; Stage: 91%; Total: 75%; ETA:   0:00:08 .. 
Progress: 205851 of 225234 done; Stage: 91%; Total: 75%; ETA:   0:00:08 ...
Progress: 205986 of 225234 done; Stage: 91%; Total: 75%; ETA:   0:00:09    
Progress: 206065 of 225234 done; Stage: 91%; Total: 76%; ETA:   0:00:09 .  
Progress: 206861 of 225234 done; Stage: 91%; Total: 76%; ETA:   0:00:09 .. 
Progress: 207366 of 225234 done; Stage: 92%; Total: 77%; ETA:   0:00:09 ...
Progress: 207394 of 225234 done; Stage: 92%; Total: 77%; ETA:   0:00:09    
Progress: 207454 of 225234 done; Stage: 92%; Total: 77%; ETA:   0:00:09 .  
Progress: 207491 of 225234 done; Stage: 92%; Total: 78%; ETA:   0:00:09 .. 
Progress: 207553 of 225234 done; Stage: 92%; Total: 78%; ETA:   0:00:09 ...
Progress: 207591 of 225234 done; Stage: 92%; Total: 78%; ETA:   0:00:09    
Progress: 207643 of 225234 done; Stage: 92%; Total: 78%; ETA:   0:00:09 .  
Progress: 207704 of 225234 done; Stage: 92%; Total: 78%; ETA:   0:00:09 .. 
Progress: 207737 of 225234 done; Stage: 92%; Total: 78%; ETA:   0:00:09 ...
Progress: 207767 of 225234 done; Stage: 92%; Total: 79%; ETA:   0:00:09    
Progress: 207827 of 225234 done; Stage: 92%; Total: 79%; ETA:   0:00:09 .  
Progress: 207900 of 225234 done; Stage: 92%; Total: 79%; ETA:   0:00:09 .. 
Progress: 207950 of 225234 done; Stage: 92%; Total: 79%; ETA:   0:00:09 ...
Progress: 208007 of 225234 done; Stage: 92%; Total: 80%; ETA:   0:00:09    
Progress: 208080 of 225234 done; Stage: 92%; Total: 80%; ETA:   0:00:09 .  
Progress: 208130 of 225234 done; Stage: 92%; Total: 80%; ETA:   0:00:09 .. 
Progress: 208179 of 225234 done; Stage: 92%; Total: 80%; ETA:   0:00:09 ...
Progress: 208184 of 225234 done; Stage: 92%; Total: 81%; ETA:   0:00:09    
Progress: 208334 of 225234 done; Stage: 92%; Total: 81%; ETA:   0:00:09 .  
Progress: 208605 of 225234 done; Stage: 92%; Total: 81%; ETA:   0:00:09 .. 
Progress: 208720 of 225234 done; Stage: 92%; Total: 81%; ETA:   0:00:09 ...
Progress: 208872 of 225234 done; Stage: 92%; Total: 81%; ETA:   0:00:09    
Progress: 208919 of 225234 done; Stage: 92%; Total: 81%; ETA:   0:00:09 .  
Progress: 209266 of 225234 done; Stage: 92%; Total: 81%; ETA:   0:00:09 .. 
Progress: 209402 of 225234 done; Stage: 92%; Total: 81%; ETA:   0:00:09 ...
Progress: 209553 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 82%; ETA:   0:00:09    
Progress: 209600 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 82%; ETA:   0:00:09 .  
Progress: 209627 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 82%; ETA:   0:00:09 .. 
Progress: 209638 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 82%; ETA:   0:00:09 ...
Progress: 209643 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 82%; ETA:   0:00:09    
Progress: 209681 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 82%; ETA:   0:00:09 .  
Progress: 209689 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 82%; ETA:   0:00:09 .. 
Progress: 209797 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 83%; ETA:   0:00:09 ...
Progress: 209823 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 83%; ETA:   0:00:09    
Progress: 209829 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 83%; ETA:   0:00:09 .  
Progress: 209837 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 84%; ETA:   0:00:09 .. 
Progress: 209851 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 84%; ETA:   0:00:09 ...
Progress: 209941 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 84%; ETA:   0:00:09    
Progress: 210086 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 84%; ETA:   0:00:09 .  
Progress: 210110 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 85%; ETA:   0:00:09 .. 
Progress: 210419 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 85%; ETA:   0:00:09 ...
Progress: 210467 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 85%; ETA:   0:00:09    
Progress: 210507 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 85%; ETA:   0:00:09 .  
Progress: 210568 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 85%; ETA:   0:00:09 .. 
Progress: 210615 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 85%; ETA:   0:00:09 ...
Progress: 210643 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 86%; ETA:   0:00:09    
Progress: 210771 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 86%; ETA:   0:00:09 .  
Progress: 210825 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 86%; ETA:   0:00:09 .. 
Progress: 210845 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 86%; ETA:   0:00:09 ...
Progress: 210850 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 86%; ETA:   0:00:09    
Progress: 210873 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 86%; ETA:   0:00:09 .  
Progress: 210914 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 86%; ETA:   0:00:09 .. 
Progress: 210993 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 87%; ETA:   0:00:09 ...
Progress: 211060 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 87%; ETA:   0:00:09    
Progress: 211105 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 87%; ETA:   0:00:09 .  
Progress: 211137 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 87%; ETA:   0:00:09 .. 
Progress: 211195 of 225234 done; Stage: 93%; Total: 87%; ETA:   0:00:09 ...
Progress: 211836 of 225234 done; Stage: 94%; Total: 87%; ETA:   0:00:09    
Progress: 212165 of 225234 done; Stage: 94%; Total: 87%; ETA:   0:00:09 .  
Progress: 212240 of 225234 done; Stage: 94%; Total: 88%; ETA:   0:00:09 .. 
Progress: 212641 of 225234 done; Stage: 94%; Total: 88%; ETA:   0:00:09 ...
Progress: 212720 of 225234 done; Stage: 94%; Total: 88%; ETA:   0:00:09    
Progress: 212743 of 225234 done; Stage: 94%; Total: 88%; ETA:   0:00:09 .  
Progress: 212749 of 225234 done; Stage: 94%; Total: 89%; ETA:   0:00:08 .. 
Progress: 212781 of 225234 done; Stage: 94%; Total: 89%; ETA:   0:00:07 ...
Progress: 213293 of 225234 done; Stage: 94%; Total: 89%; ETA:   0:00:07    
Progress: 213430 of 225234 done; Stage: 94%; Total: 90%; ETA:   0:00:07 .  
Progress: 213578 of 225234 done; Stage: 94%; Total: 90%; ETA:   0:00:07 .. 
Progress: 213624 of 225234 done; Stage: 94%; Total: 90%; ETA:   0:00:07 ...
Progress: 213693 of 225234 done; Stage: 94%; Total: 90%; ETA:   0:00:07    
Progress: 213730 of 225234 done; Stage: 94%; Total: 90%; ETA:   0:00:07 .  
Progress: 213809 of 225234 done; Stage: 94%; Total: 90%; ETA:   0:00:07 .. 
Progress: 213819 of 225234 done; Stage: 94%; Total: 90%; ETA:   0:00:07 ...
Progress: 213891 of 225234 done; Stage: 94%; Total: 90%; ETA:   0:00:07    
Progress: 214128 of 225234 done; Stage: 95%; Total: 91%; ETA:   0:00:07 .  
Progress: 225234 of 225234 done; Stage: 100%; Total: 91%; ETA:   0:00:06 .. 


  225234 index entries processed.                                                       

Index verification completed.
Progress: 0 of 0 done; Stage: 99%; Total: 91%; ETA:   0:00:06 ...


  0 unindexed files scanned.                                        

Progress: 0 of 0 done; Stage: 99%; Total: 91%; ETA:   0:00:06    


  0 unindexed files recovered.                                      


Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Security descriptor verification completed.
Progress: 1 of 1 done; Stage: 100%; Total: 99%; ETA:   0:00:00 .  


  10986 data files processed.                                           

CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
Progress: 0 of 1228 done; Stage:  0%; Total: 99%; ETA:   0:00:00 .. 
Progress: 131 of 1228 done; Stage: 10%; Total: 99%; ETA:   0:00:00 ...
Progress: 1049 of 1228 done; Stage: 85%; Total: 99%; ETA:   0:00:00    
Progress: 1228 of 1228 done; Stage: 100%; Total: 99%; ETA:   0:00:00 .  

                                                                                       10064304 USN bytes processed.                                                           

Usn Journal verification completed.

Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
No further action is required.

 976756735 KB total disk space.
 262122464 KB in 192140 files.
     51752 KB in 10987 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
    309295 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
 714273224 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
 244189183 total allocation units on disk.
 178568306 allocation units available on disk.
```

Now I only want the text of this string from :
Usn Journal verification completed.

Till the end of the string.

How do I do this??

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: We probably didn't need the entire string... for future reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a `string[]`:

```
var relevantLines = allLines
  .SkipWhile(l => !l.StartsWith("Usn Journal verification completed", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));  // omit the second parameter if you want to compare case sensitive
```

Otherwise use `string.Split`:

```
string[] allLines = allText
  .Split(new[]{ Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

If you want a string as final result use `string.Join`:

```
string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, relevantLines);
```

Comment: Ohh so basically I need to convert my string into a string[] and then search for the string[] that contains the right text and then get the text from all next string[] items.

Comment: @Nobleleader13245: Yes, if it's a file you can use `File.ReadLines` or `File.ReadAllLines`. If you need astring as result you can use `string.Join`(edited my naswer).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is probably just to find the string "Usn Journal Verification completed" and take a substring from there:

```
string s = ???; // your string
int pos = s.IndexOf("Usn Journal Verification completed");
string outString = s.Substring(pos);
```

You'll need to do some error checking to make sure the string was found etc.